# Listview Clearing/resetting/finish not working

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I've got an Android application with 2 activities
First (main) activity: Dropdown with available XML files
Second (list) acitvity: Show results in a ListView / Listadapter

The application works fine, but when I use the Back button on the second activity it finishes the application and clears the ArrayList (tested with System.out) and choose another XML view, the old XML results are shown.

So basically it looks like the listview still apears in my memory, how do I clear/reset this??

```
        XMLParse parser = new XMLParse();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
            //SOME CODE//

    // Adding menuItems to ListView
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { bestemming, vertrek, spoor, vertraging }, new int[] {
                    R.id.bestemming, R.id.vertrek, R.id.spoor, R.id.vertraging });
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            menuItems.clear();
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can u be clrearer? Maybe post some code?

Comment: Where is the `ArrayList` defined in your app ?

Comment: ArrayList is defined in the 2n activity, so in the same activity that uses finish()

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with ArrayAdapter?

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter ...
...
menuItems.clear();
adapter.clear();
...
```

or

```
listView.setAdapter(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to notify adapter that you have changed ArrayList and it will redraw this. Sometimes it redraws without notification but sometimes it shows old data.

In your main activity try to use something like that:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```